# Transfer MP3s with metadata from iTunes to Apple Music

Tags: itunes, music, metadata, mp3

I have ~6,000 MP3's on my old iMac in an iTunes folder, using the old iTunes `Library.itl` and `iTunes Music Library.xml` file structure.

I have a new MBA with Apple Music and ~20 MP3 files using the `Music Library.musiclibrary` file structure.

I have transferred the old iTunes folder onto the MBA.

How can I move the ~6,000 MP3s into the Apple Music library and persevere the metadata (the "Date Added" is super important to me)?

The end goal is to delete the iTunes folder and have all MP3s in Apple Music in date order of when I bought them, and using all the new Music app file structure and having no trace of iTunes etc. on my MBA.

Comment: Apple's Migration Assistant is designed to exactly that type of thing, *move your files and settings from one Mac to another.* Do you have a specific reason for not using Migration Assistant?

Comment: Because it keeps all the old iTunes files around on the new Mac. I want a clean slate.

Comment: Where do you expect the files to end up once you import them into Apple Music?

Comment: In the Music folder within Apple Music